# SQL insert query not working with JQuery UI datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

The html input:

```
<input name="week_ending" type="text" id="week_ending" value="" />
```

The jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#week_ending" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

The PHP code:

```
$week_ending = db_quote($_POST['week_ending']);

function db_quote($value) {
    $connection = db_connect();
    return "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value) . "'";
}
```

The SQL:

```
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `timesheets` (clientid, candid, weekending, department, orderno, basicpay, basiccharge, otpay, otcharge, ot2pay, ot2charge, status, hue, huc) VALUES ($client, $cand, $week_ending, $department, $order_no, $basic_pay, $basic_charge, $ot_pay, $ot_charge, $ot2_pay, $ot2_charge, $status, $hue, $huc)");
    if($result){
        print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is';
    } 
    else {
        die('Error : ' . db_error());
    }
```

Every row I insert to `timesheets` has the date as `0000-00-00`. The data type is set to `date` in the `timesheets` table.

When inspecting the element after a date has been chosen the HTML is:

```
<input class="hasDatepicker" name="week_ending" id="week_ending" value="" type="text">
```

I'm guessing that explains the `0000-00-00` going into the database. I've tried to add `.formatDate` but that doesn't seem to make a difference and tried changing to `<input type="date">` but still nothing is appearing in the `value` property

Comment: Does it work when you specify mysql compatible date format i.e. `.datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"})`

Comment: @SalmanA That works, `$( "#week_ending" ).datepicker().formatDate( "yy-mm-dd");` didn't?? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP functions: `date()` and `strtotime` to parse the format into a timestamp and then into correct date format.

Be aware that users can change the input field with wrong data.

```
$week_ending = db_quote(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['week_ending'])));
```